# Got this error "Your Android App Bundle file has not been signed with the correct key. Make sure to use the SHA1 signing key" after upload .abb file

Tags: android

I have a big problem. i follow this tutorial step by step
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key.
I build my sign .abb file and i got this error after i uploaded it on google play console :

"Your Android App Bundle file has not been signed with the correct key. Make sure to use the SHA1 signing key : XX:XX...."

I don't know why .. and i don't know what to do next .. i've already tried everything..

Edit :
Solved !
i create my app withs react native and i build my apk / abb file with android studio and on google play console i have deleted and recreated a new app and its working

Answer (score 0):

Is this the first apk/aab uploaded for this app?

Judging by the error, it seems like the first apk/aab uploaded to google play console uses a different key (another .jks/.keystore file) then the one you are using right now.

If you lost access to the original key, and opted-in Play Managed Signature, you can easily request a key reset in (Your App > Settings > App Signing > Request Key Upgrade > Lost access...)

If you didn't opt in, I have sad news for you... :(

Comment: Hi, yes this is my first apk/aab uploaded
i've tried to delete my app and create a new app in google play console, but i got this error again.. so i don't know

Comment: It is really strange that you are getting a Invalid key on the first upload, did you check all the tracks (internal, alpha, beta) if there's an apk uploaded there?